# Dynamic minimum/maximum values for Rails mode validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the length validator for a model and it's working fine.

```
validates :my_field, length: {minimum: 10, maximum: 100}
```

I'm trying to use the value dynamically. For instance, I want to get the values from Preference model.

```
validates :my_field, length: {minimum: Preference.int_value("my.minimum"), maximum: Preference.int_value("my.maximum")}
```

This code is working fine before I change the value of the Preference model.
**If I change the value from 10 to 5, it doesn't affect the result of the model validation.**

It seems the validates method is loaded in memory and **fix the value** when server started.

How can I perform a dynamic length validation?

Comment: you can always resort to a custom validation, but that's for sure not an answer and I am interested to know, how validaitions are loaded

Comment: Try to handle it dynamically,  with Proc. something like `length: {minimum: Proc.new {Preference.int_value("my.minimum")}, ...`

Comment: @dimuch Doesn't look like `minimum` or `maximum` can be a `Proc` for length validation.

Comment: Yep, that's true. It works fine in `greater_than` / `less_than`, but fails in `minimum`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self answer.

I created a custom validator that inherit built in length validator and **override** two methods of the super class that make the validator can accept **lambda** as a value. This make validator can `call` **block** in runtime.

```
class MyLengthValidator < ActiveModel::Validations::LengthValidator

  def check_validity!
    keys = CHECKS.keys & options.keys

    if keys.empty?
      raise ArgumentError, 'Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.'
    end

    keys.each do |key|
      # !!!!! Here is the point that I've customized !!!!!
      value = options[key].is_a?(Proc) ? options[key].call : options[key]

      unless (value.is_a?(Integer) && value >= 0) || value == Float::INFINITY
        raise ArgumentError, ":#{key} must be a nonnegative Integer or Infinity"
      end
    end
  end

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    value = tokenize(record, value)
    value_length = value.respond_to?(:length) ? value.length : value.to_s.length
    errors_options = options.except(*RESERVED_OPTIONS)

    CHECKS.each do |key, validity_check|

      # !!!!! Here is the point that I've customized !!!!!
      next unless check_value = options[key].is_a?(Proc) ? options[key].call : options[key]

      if !value.nil? || skip_nil_check?(key)
        next if value_length.send(validity_check, check_value)
      end

      errors_options[:count] = check_value

      default_message = options[MESSAGES[key]]
      errors_options[:message] ||= default_message if default_message

      record.errors.add(attribute, MESSAGES[key], errors_options)
    end
  end

end
```

And pass lambda as a value for custom length validator options:

```
validates :my_field, my_length: {
   minimum: -> { Preference.int_value("my.minimum") }, 
   maximum: -> { Preference.int_value("my.maximum") } 
}
```

Can refer this closed PR when you need: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21730/files